# WooCommerce customer mail custom-get name

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have the following custom form with code added to the functions.php file:

```html
* ----------------------------------Checkout Field Stor data Start----------------------------------*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['account_per_title'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, ' Account Title', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_per_title'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['account_fname'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account First Name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_fname'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['account_mname'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account Middle Name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_mname'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['account_lname'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account Last Name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_lname'] ) );
    }
```

And here in the template I want to display the name of the person filling in the order:

```html
<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html ($order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Order number */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know — we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>
```

Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: Solution:  add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'processing_order_replacement_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function processing_order_replacement_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set HERE your replacement recipient email(s)… (If multiple, separate them by a coma)
    $recipient = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Account Email', true ) ;
    return $recipient;
}

Answer (score 0):

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'processing_order_replacement_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function processing_order_replacement_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set HERE your replacement recipient email(s)… (If multiple, separate them by a coma)
    $recipient = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Account Email', true ) ;
    return $recipient;
}
```